# Advice Needed for Honeycomb App Upgrade.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have been doing some research on the upgrading my app (android:maxSdkVersion = “10”) to Honeycomb and would like some advice.

First, one of the activities in my application is a List Activity. Once the user selects an item from the listview, a new activity/layout starts that gives information about the item selected from the listview.  The user must then back out of the info screen to get back to the listview. (Simple)

If I move this application to Honeycomb, then I can use Fragments. Using Fragments, I can use both of the above mentioned activities on the screen at once.

Now the dilemma. If I use Fragments to get the functionality I would like, but then I will have to use the Android Compatibility library in order for my FROYO users to use the application. And by using the Android Compatibility library I will bind my application to a lower level of honeycomb OS.

So, if I want to continue upgrading my application past ICE CREAM, then the best thing to do might be to create one application that remains maxSdkVersion = “10” and a second application using minSdkVersion=”11”.

So, for a paid app, users will have to buy two versions of the application?

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, for a paid app, users will have to buy two versions of the
>   application?

If you are using Google Market then, no, you can upload multiple apks and target different configurations using some constraints.

You can read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html) post from the official android dev blog

Comment: That's some good reading. That's exactly what I need to do once we have handsets and tablets running the same OS. However, I did not see anything about running two APK's. Are you saying that I can go into the Android market and add a second APK to my already published app? So, only the applicable device will see the APK?

Comment: Further... If I do run two APK's for the same app, under the same published app, then I assume that download counts are combined?

Comment: Yes, the market will choose the right apk, nothing will change from the users perspective. In terms of download counts I'm not 100% sure, but I assume any apk download will count as an app download.